# Facebook developers sidebar api not found

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook api for a while now but I can't find any thing related to the sidebar (like in the pic below) inside developers.facebook.com

[image]

Is such service exist?!!

Comment: There is no API for ticker.

Comment: @WizKid but it did exist in the pass, right? like in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CftHdEMbUJk , why did they remove it ?

Comment: That was just plugin to show recent activity on a page. It has nothing to do with ticker. There never been an API for that